# Ignored testfor parameters

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

So I was was using the /testfor command (Specifically `/testfor @p[x=,y=,z=]`), but it activated before I went to the specified coordinates. Can someone please help me? (By the way, it activated without power earlier).

Comment: Did you put numbers after each `=` sign?

Comment: A general tip: Use `@a` instead of `@p`

Comment: I did put numbers after the = signs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify the `x`, `y`, and `z` parameters, all that it's doing is changing the origin of execution. Instead of selecting the nearest player to the command block, you're selecting the nearest player to the specified coordinates.

But since you did not place any area limiters, it's going to look for a player no matter how far away they are. You will want to include a limiter such as `r` (radius), stating the number of blocks outward in each direction from the origin to find a player within.

For example, the following looks for the closest player within 5 blocks of (10, 64, 10):

```
/testfor @p[x=10,y=64,z=10,r=5]
```

Comment: Thx. BTW OMG SKYLINER ANSWERED MY QUESTION. EDIT: I just tested it and it won't work. ;-;

Comment: @TDM2 If you've changed any part of the command you will need to provide the modified command. Instead of saying it "won't work", say *why* it won't work (such as providing the error message). If the error is akin to "invalid UUID format", then that will typically mean no target was found (meaning no players within 5 blocks of the coordinates).

Comment: The command is 'testfor @p[x=150,y=4,z=-930,r=1]' The console of the command block says 'Found TheRedstonerPro', but the comparator isn't activated.